# If I have 2 distinct csv files, how do I use one of them for training and the other for testing a sklearn logistic regression model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Whenever I try and clean the individual CSV files, I keep running into value errors whenever I try and predict probabilities. Is there any way I can train a model on 1 CSV file, keep it, and then gather some testing data in another CSV file and feed the latter file through the model I trained using the first file?

P.S. It is important that I do not use train_test_split, as I want information about each individual class (as they have I.Ds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps

1. Make a function that takes care of all the **data handling** tasks such as reading the csv file, cleaning the data etc. Using the function, read the test csv file and set the encoders and other transform parameters.
2. Read the files using the function, make user to **set the parameters** only based on the training data. For testing data only transform the features.
3. Also it's important to keep in mind that both the csv files have the **same columns** and the order of the columns is also important.
4. **Fit the model** on the training data only, use the testing data for **predictions and scoring**.

```py
# Training csv
train = read_csv('train.csv')

# Transform and clean data
# Fit function

# Testing csv
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# Transform and fit the data
# Predict and score using the testing data
```